# Codename one multilist image- new gui builder

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to create a multilist with 5 items, each one containing an image, and some information.

Image 1, text 2, phone 2
Image 2, text 2, phone 2
etc.

I am currently unable to insert an image picked from .res file in the old gui builder, it only displays key and string-just text.
Is there any way in the "key" value to put images in the multilist?

EXTRA:
Every time i enable "scrollable y" in the form, it disappears when I leave the GUI designer. Is this a bug? Am I able to fix it with code or other way?

[image: multilist]

Answer (score 0):

The multi-list itself is scrollable so it should handle the scrolling. I don'tthink the new GUI builder supports images in the multi-list as we migrated away from using these components see https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html